# How to auto start docker containers in Docker for mac?

Tags: docker, docker-for-mac, docker-desktop

**Docker Desktop for Mac** restarts every time my laptop wakes up and I have to manually start all my containers by `docker start <container>`. Is there a way to do it automatically?

Comment: Seems like odd behavior though, one I haven't experienced on Mac with Docker beta or Vagrant-based Docker hosts. So you might want to look into why it's not restoring the VM state, but as mentioned, in any case you can set a restart policy like `--restart unless-stopped` or similar.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try and run your containers with the `--restart always` policy.
See [`docker run` Restart policies](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#/restart-policies-restart).

> Always restart the container regardless of the exit status.
>   When you specify always, the Docker daemon will try to restart the container indefinitely.
>   The container will also always start on daemon startup, regardless of the current state of the container.

That way, when the docker daemon restart, all containers previously launched with that option should run again.